# IIS connectivity issue from remote machine

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7

[image: WireShark Log]

I have IIS installed in a WIN7 machine(Server), when i am trying to connect to this system from a remote machine on the same network using `<http://ServerMachineName>`, it fails.

I took a snapshot of the wireshark log as shown in the pic above.
Please have a look and let me know if you are able to detect the reason.

Comment: Check the firewalls on the machines involved and on the network between them. It is entirely possible that traffic is being blocked.

Comment: @Oded: If traffic is blocked, i would not be able to see these packets in wireshark, right?

Comment: Then explain what you mean by "it fails". The words by themselves mean nothing - _what_ fails?

Comment: @Oded: The client machine is not able to access the server page and it says ,"Internet explorer cannot display the webpage"

Comment: And port 80 is not blocked? You say that wireshark shows that traffic is coming through - I see the 200. Do you see the full HTML payload?

Comment: Can you see the page in any other browser?

Comment: @Oded: No, I am not able to see in any browser